# While using Bootstrap-Vue, how do you prevent a b-dropdown from closing when clicking on a nested b-input component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, pug, bootstrap-vue

I'm pretty sure I just don't understand how to implement Vue's [Event Modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers). According to that documentation, all I have to do is add this:

```
<!-- the click event's propagation will be stopped -->
<a v-on:click.stop="doThis"></a>
```

Here's how I interpreted the example into my pug code:

```
b-dropdown(text="Actions")
  b-dropdown-item
    b-form(inline)
      .row
        .col
          b-input(@click.stop='' placeholder="#123")
          b-button(:href='printCheck' variant="primary") Print Check
```

It looks pretty simple, however it's not working as expected. If you need more supporting info, just ask. And feel free to tweak the title; I wasn't sure if my question is a vue, bootstrap-vue, or javascript question.

Thanks for your time in advance,

Kevin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're clicking on a component you should combine `.native` with `.stop` modifiers like so :

```
 b-input(@click.native.stop='' placeholder="#123")
```

if you're using a simple HTML element like `input` you could use only `.stop` modifier:

```
 input(@click.stop='' placeholder="#123")
```

Comment: I think that did the trick! I just played with this code snippet at https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/dropdown# and it worked: `<div>
  <b-dropdown id="ddown1" text="Dropdown Button" class="m-md-2">
    <b-dropdown-item>
      <b-form>
        <b-input @click.native.stop placeholder="check number"></b-input>
      </b-form>
    </b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>
</div>`

Answer (score 3):

You can now use the new `<b-dropdown-form>` sub-component for placing input fields into dropdowns.

You should avoid placing input controls inside `<b-dropdown-item>` (which renders an `<a>` as it's root element), or `<b-dropdown-item-button>` (which renders a `<button>` as its root element).  HTML5 doesn't like interactive elements inside `<a>` or `<button>` elements.

`<b-dropdown-form>` does not auto-close the dropdown when it is clicked.