# How can one check the listeners on a button element that isn't working when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, google-chrome-devtools

[Earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53639701/while-using-bootstrap-vue-how-do-you-prevent-a-b-dropdown-from-closing-when-cli), I had a problem with a nested b-input's [event modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) not functioning correctly. I had to insert a `.native` like so since I was clicking on a component:

```
      b-dropdown(text="Actions")
        b-dropdown-item(:href='settlementPdf' target='_blank') Download PDF
        b-dropdown-item
          b-form(inline)
            .row
              .col
                b-input(v-model='checkNumber' @click.native.stop='' placeholder="#123")
                b-button(:href='printCheck' variant="primary" target='_blank') Print Check
```

My problem now is that the `b-button` right below the `b-input` is no longer working when clicked on. How can I troubleshoot this and see that there is no longer a listener listening for a click event? I assume that is the problem, but please correct/direct me if I'm wrong!

I'm looking for a `give a man a fish and feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and feed him for a lifetime` type of answer. Can I use chrome dev tools to look at the type of events being listened for on that button element?

Comment: what does mean `printCheck` of href attribute?

Comment: It's a Vue calculate method

Comment: you want to call that method by clicking on button?

Comment: Sorry at a bowling league! My mistake it's called computed in Vue, not calculate. No it runs a method that returns a URL string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the element, and select `Inspect` from the menu to find the element in the `Elements` tab of DevTools.

Then go to the `Event Listeners` tab in the sidebar, and expand the `click` listeners. You can also uncheck the "Ancestors" checkbox so you only see listeners attached directly to that element, rather than listeners on containing elements (which will receive events due to bubbling).